FIX API , unable to receive all the positions
I am connecting to my ctrader platform using FIX protocol.
I have about 8 positions open in HK50 , however when I send a message, only 1 position is returned.
Below is the log of the socket connection and response. I am not receiving the message.
DEBUG:root:SEND >>> 8=FIX.4.4|9=95|35=AN|49=demo.pepperstone.3965339|50=TRADE|56=CSERVER|57=TRADE|34=3|52=20240804-13:19:11|710=1|10=235|
DEBUG:root:SEND >>> 8=FIX.4.4|9=101|35=AF|49=demo.pepperstone.3965339|50=TRADE|56=CSERVER|57=TRADE|34=4|52=20240804-13:19:11|584=1|585=7|10=040|
DEBUG:root:RECV <<< 8=FIX.4.4|9=165|35=AP|34=2|49=CSERVER|50=TRADE|52=20240804-13:19:11.823|56=demo.pepperstone.3965339|57=TRADE|55=10004|710=1|721=133438135|727=12|728=0|730=16949.3|702=1|704=7|705=0|10=225|
8=FIX.4.4|9=139|35=V|49=demo.pepperstone.3965339|50=QUOTE|56=CSERVER|57=QUOTE|34=4|52=20240804-13:19:11|262=1|263=1|264=1|267=2|269=0|269=1|146=1|55=10004|10=010|
DEBUG:root:SEND >>> 8=FIX.4.4|9=139|35=V|49=demo.pepperstone.3965339|50=QUOTE|56=CSERVER|57=QUOTE|34=4|52=20240804-13:19:11|262=1|263=1|264=1|267=2|269=0|269=1|146=1|55=10004|10=010|
INFO:root:Market is Close or Logged out 'USDK50'
DEBUG:root:RECV <<< 8=FIX.4.4|9=139|35=W|34=3|49=CSERVER|50=QUOTE|52=20240804-13:19:11.943|56=demo.pepperstone.3965339|57=QUOTE|55=10004|268=2|269=0|270=16890|269=1|270=16895|10=116|
position_list_callback---- {'133438135': {'pos_id': '133438135', 'name': 'HK50', 'long': 7.0, 'short': 0.0, 'price': 16949.3, 'digits': 1, 'clid': None, 'convert': 'USDK50', 'convert_dir': 1}}
DEBUG:root:client_id 1 positions: [{'pos_id': '133438135', 'name': 'HK50', 'side': 'Buy', 'amount': 7.0, 'price': '16949.3', 'actual_price': '16890.0', 'diff': '-59.3', 'pl': '-415.10', 'gain': ''}]
DEBUG:root:client_id 1 orders: []
[{'pos_id': '133438135', 'name': 'HK50', 'side': 'Buy', 'amount': 7.0, 'price': '16949.3', 'actual_price': '16890.0', 'diff': '-59.3', 'pl': '-415.10', 'gain': ''}]

I am looking to get all positions which are open

Normally you should get multiple position reports sent. How are your reading from server? i am able to get all position reports for a different symbol tho. According to tage 727 in your AP response you should have 12 positions reports streamed
